# Reading double from file

Tags: c++, double, readfile

For my homework I should read double values from a file and sort them. These are the some of the values. But when read them with my code, when a print it for testing they are written in integer form.

```
std::ifstream infile (in_File);
double a;
while(infile>>a)
{
    std::cout<<a<<std::endl;
}
```

My doubles are started with `185261.886524` then `237358.956723`

And my code print the `185262` then `237359` then so on.

Comment: Works for me. Can you post the contents of your file?

Comment: 185261.886524
237358.956723
139921.832662
128702.977104
93468.067919
415572.438294
394341.383634
317808.343493
63075.462939
907012.789025
393656.286891
418873.927354
892347.117718
764276.357958
300568.750436
717272.259456
354591.446610
431749.187142
63565.857898
288241.215494
526117.693273
680793.623315
68218.415160
391965.952529
66870.811087
3982.888630
469794.327128
492466.036574 and go on

Comment: Actually I wanna add a picture but system does not allow me

Comment: I don't know what is the locale settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding this at the top of your `main()`:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "C");
```

[This](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clocale/setlocale/) will give your program the "C" locale instead of your local one.  I imagine your local one uses "," as a decimal point instead of "." as in your data.

You will need to add `#include <clocale>` at the top of your file as well.

Edit: then, to get more precision, you can do `#include <iomanip>` and do this at the top of your program:

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(20);
```

[`setprecision`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/) changes how many total digits are printed.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work.Yes we are using "," in local .When I write the file 2.33 it works perfectly but when the number get bigger i.e 185261.886524 it gets 185262

Comment: Try some different numbers to find out exactly which ones work and which don't.

Comment: 1852.88 also works then become not work.1852.887 become 1852.88

Comment: I think IO streams only print 6 significant digits by default, which matches what the OP is experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not the input, but the output: `cout` by default prints 6 digits of a `double`, this is why you see the rounded value `185262`, not `185261` as you would expect from incorrect input. Use [`std::setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) to increase output precision.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if on your system your localization settings have a different decimal separator than `.`. Try add the following include:

```
#include <locale>
```

and then use the [`imbue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/imbue) method:

```
std::ifstream infile (in_File);
infile.imbue(std::locale("C"));
double a;
while(infile>>a)
{
    std::cout<<a<<std::endl;
}
```